# SumoSelect won't open after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, multi-select, sumoselect.js

I am using [sumoselect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) on inputs in my web.

Problem is - if you open second sumoselect and after that you want open first -so click on first and he is not opening...

My code:

```
$('.country').SumoSelect({placeholder: 'first'});
$('.anotherSumo').SumoSelect({placeholder: 'second'});

$('.anotherSumo').on('sumo:closing', function(e) {

  $('.country').empty();
  $('.country').append('<option value="newValue">newValue</option>');
  $('.country')[0].sumo.reload({placeholder: 'first'});
});
```

Here is working fiddle. Just open second select and after that try open first - 2 clicks. In reversed order - first click to open first sumo and after that second click on second sumo is everything ok...

I was trying add `$('country').trigger("click");` after reload but nothing

https://jsfiddle.net/eqa9og2v/5/

I need to know how to open first sumo on second click any way but with funcional trigger on sumoselect close - because first user make his choices and if is user done with selecting options he close sumoselect (with open another or only close)

Comment: changing `sumo:closing` to `sumo:opening` does the trick. So is there any problem with `sumo:opening`? as per your code i don't think so.

Comment: `sumo:opening` is problem for me because user must first select options and after that is sumo close and after that i changing values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out... There is way to do it! I needed exacly this - if you have some notices or whatever you are welcome.

My code:

```
$('.country').SumoSelect({placeholder: 'first'});
$('.anotherSumo').SumoSelect({placeholder: 'second'});

$('.anotherSumo').on('sumo:closed', function(e) { 

    var count = $('.country option').length;

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        $('.country')[0].sumo.remove(0);    
    }

    $('.country')[0].sumo.add('newValue','newValue', 0);
});
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eqa9og2v/7/

NOTICE: If you need properly working inputs (for send form or what) you need add/remove `option` elements in `select` by own way too...

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you are trying to implement is not feasible and will not be possible to achieve because when you click on the 1st to open it, 2nd drop-down closing is called in which you recreates the 1st again. so the actual click of the 1st drop down is lost as all the new bindings are added to the 1st drop down.

you have to change the code in the plugin if you want to achive it which is not a good practise. Also you can force the 1st dropdown to show the options by using `$('.sumo_country').addClass('open').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');` but again for closing the dropdown you have to click twice for 1st time.

The proper and feasible way to change any drop down values which are depending on other is by using the `change` function of the drop down.

In your case you have to change the data whenever the value is selected or deselected from 2nd drop down which will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example. As you mentioned in comments you want to change the 1st select after selecting something from 2nd, not just after closing it.
`.on('change', ...)` seems to do the trick.

https://jsfiddle.net/eqa9og2v/6/

Comment: It is not working... Yes after click is sumo opening but without any changes... Without 'newValue'... Result of your code is like only init both sumoselects nothing more...

Comment: Ok, sorry, then I think your requirement does not make sense o me. Why do you want to change content of sumo1 if user does not select anything in sumo2? I thought the content should change according to the selection and this solution fits the need.

Comment: I am look on your question very quick so i can't see that your answer is good idea but in my case is sadly unusable because on web are 3 select options - country, area and place and they are connected so `.on('change')` event fired by user triggers my code whitch changes in all inputs options...